# MPAndroidChart: How to show limit lines without showing the Y Axis?

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I have tried doing

```
getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
```

But with this line of code, the limit lines also disappear.
what's the solution for this?

[image: Something like this!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YAxis left = mChart.getAxisLeft();
left.setDrawLabels(false); // no axis labels
left.setDrawAxisLine(false); // no axis line
left.setDrawGridLines(false); // no grid lines
left.setDrawZeroLine(true); // draw a zero line
mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false); // no right axis
```

Maybe you can use like this:

```
YAxis left = mChart.getAxisLeft();
left.setDrawLabels(false);
left.setDrawAxisLine(true);
```